# Checking for duplicate rows and adding new information with BindingSource

Tags: .net, vb.net

I hope you all are having a great week!

I am currently having some trouble with the code below. Basically I am searching for existing rows. If the duplicate row doesn't exist, then we add a new one, otherwise we writeover the information like so:

```
For Each FindRows As DataRow In dset.Tables("Table1").Rows

    Dim FindMYID As Integer = myBindingSource.Find("MYID", FindRows(0).ToString)
    'If MYID does not exist
    If FindMYID < 0 Then
        myBindingSource.AddNew()
    End If


    CType(myBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)("MYID") = FindRows(0).ToString
    CType(myBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)("Name") = FindRows(1).ToString
    CType(myBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)("P1") = FindRows(2).ToString
    CType(myBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)("P2") = FindRows(3).ToString
    CType(myBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)("P3") = FindRows(4).ToString
    CType(myBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)("P4") = FindRows(5).ToString
    CType(myBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)("P5") = FindRows(6).ToString

    If FindRows(7) IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso FindRows(8) IsNot DBNull.Value Then 
        If Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(7)) / Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(8)) >= 0.25 Then
            bhkBox1.Checked = False
        Else
            bhkBox1.Checked = True
        End If
    End If

    If FindRows(9) IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso FindRows(10) IsNot DBNull.Value Then 
        If Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(9)) / Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(10)) >= 0.2 Then
            bhkBox2.Checked = False
        Else
            bhkBox2.Checked = True
        End If
    End If

    If FindRows(15) IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso FindRows(12) IsNot DBNull.Value Then 
        If Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(15)) / Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(12)) >= 0.4 Then
            bhkBox3.Checked = False
        Else
            bhkBox3.Checked = True
        End If
    End If

    If FindRows(13) IsNot DBNull.Value Then 
        If Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(13)) >= 10 Then
            bhkBox4.Checked = False
        Else
            bhkBox4.Checked = True
        End If
    End If

    If FindRows(14) IsNot DBNull.Value Then 
        If Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(14)) > 0 Then
            bhkBox5.Checked = False
        Else
            bhkBox5.Checked = True
        End If
    End If

    If FindRows(16) IsNot DBNull.Value Then 
        If Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(16)) > 0 Then
            bhkBox6.Checked = False
        Else
            bhkBox6.Checked = True
        End If
    End If

    If FindRows(17) IsNot DBNull.Value Then 
        If Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(17)) > 0 Then
            bhkBox7.Checked = False
        Else
            bhkBox7.Checked = True
        End If
    End If

    If FindRows(18) IsNot DBNull.Value Then 
        If Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(18)) > 0 Then
            bhkBox8.Checked = False
        Else
            bhkBox8.Checked = True
        End If
    End If

    If FindRows(19) IsNot DBNull.Value Then
        If Convert.ToDouble(FindRows(19)) > 0 Then
            bhkBox9.Checked = False
        Else
            bhkBox9.Checked = True
        End If
    End If

    myBindingSource.EndEdit()
Next
```

The issue is that it does NOT overwrite the information. It definitely finds the rows that exists and it's definitely reading the information correctly, but it's not "saved" - meaning when the information is displayed in my DataGridView, the information that was supposed to have been written over and such is blank. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Steve! I don't even know how you do that.

Comment: When in edit mode select your code and click the button {}  the code should have at least 4 spaces indent.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh. Thanks!

Comment: was the information blank before being overwritten?

Comment: also, are you trying just to act on the checkboxes?

Comment: @FrancescoB. Yes they were, but moving forward after getting everything working some information will be blank, and some will not. I'm trying to add stuff to my textboxes as well as changing the checkbox.checkstate.